# How to create a Hyperlink with Argument to a user field?

Tags: acumatica

I want to hyper-link a grid cell which take an argument?

```
<px:PXNumberEdit ID="edOpenTimeID" runat="server" DataField="OpenTimeID">
    <LinkCommand ActiveBehavior="True" Argument="OpenTimeID" Command="ViewOpenTime">
    </LinkCommand>
</px:PXNumberEdit>
```

I found something like that [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26387291/how-to-create-a-hyperlink-user-field/26439423#26439423) but, it does not take an argument.
Thanks a lot

Comment: What kind of url you want to make?

Comment: What do you want to do with this argument? When invoking your ViewOpenTime command, you will already have access to the current row of your grid, and from there you do whatever action or redirect you want.

Answer (score 0):

I not sure is it really what you want, but I propose you the following solution (this is part of my working project).
1. In grid declaration:

```
<Columns>
    <px:PXGridColumn DataField="IsNotCalculated" Width="1px" RenderEditorText="True" >
                    </px:PXGridColumn>
                     <px:PXGridColumn DataField="PRPayrollDetailID" Width="90px" LinkCommand="GotoPayslip">
                        <ValueItems MultiSelect="False">
                        </ValueItems>
                    </px:PXGridColumn>
```

3. In graph I described the following:

   public PXAction GotoPayslip;

   [PXButton]
   [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Go to Payslip")]
   public virtual IEnumerable gotoPayslip(PXAdapter adapter)
   {
               if (PayRollsDetails.Current != null)
               {
                   var graph = CreateInstance();
                   graph.PaySlip.Current =
                       graph.PaySlip.SearchPRPayrollDetails.payrollRefNbr>(
                           PayRollsDetails.Current.PRPayrollDetailID, 
   PayRollsDetails.Current.PayrollRefNbr);
                   throw new PXRedirectRequiredException(graph, true, "");
               }
               return adapter.Get();
           }

If to summarize in simple words: 
1. At grid syncposition = true. 
2. At column set DataField and LincCommand. 
3. At graph you'll need PXAction declaration and implementation, which will differ from each other by case. 
4. You can read and use paramethers at graph.

Comment: I believe you forget to mention one more detail. You need to add <px:PXDSCallbackCommand Name="GotoPayslip" Visible="False" DependOnGrid="grid"> </px:PXDSCallbackCommand> in PXDataSource declaration of page

Comment: @Ahmed Mahany did it help?

Comment: If you dont have grid ? for example if you want to set link command on  form  view , then?

Comment: In such case you can use button that will redirect you. Button will be located on the form around navigation buttons