# how to use AllowEdit in Acumatica

Tags: c#, erp, acumatica

I'm having this problem:

I'd like to try to make a pop up for `CrossSection` table page using `AllowEdit = "true"`, the pencil symbol has already showed, but it doesn't open anything, I already entered the page of `CrossSection` into hidden in `SiteMap`. Is there any step I miss to use `AllowEdit`? How can I use `AllowEdit`?

Comment: Could you show us the declaration of the field in the DAC?

So we can see a bit more what you are doing.

Comment: To have navigation from the `AllowEdit` one must have the `PXSelector` attribute on the corresponding DAC field. Do you have one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Along with `PXSelector` attribute and `AllowEdit` for `PXSelector` aspx control, make sure to set the primary graph for the DAC. 
The primary graph determines the default page where a user is redirected for editing a data record.

Example:

```
[PXPrimaryGraph(typeof(CrossSectionMaint))]
[Serializable]
public class CrossSection : PX.Data.IBqlTable
{
...
}
```

Comment: I have done same but still link doesn't open popup.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a full answer, but may be a necessary step.

I found that my grid field did not allow me to set the `AllowEdit` property, by which I mean, it simply did not exist. It was a `PXSelector` etc etc, but different than a normal, stand-alone selector. I even tried adding the `AllowEdit` code manually, but it was removed upon saving.

Browsing another grid that had a selector with links, I discovered a `RowTemplate` section, which I have not seen before.

```
<px:PXTabItem Text="Salespersons" LoadOnDemand="True">
    <Template>
      <px:PXGrid ID="PXGrid1" runat="server" Height="300px" Width="100%" SkinID="DetailsInTab" DataSourceID="ds">
        <Levels>
          <px:PXGridLevel DataMember="SalesPersons" DataKeyNames="SalesPersonID,LocationID">
            <Columns>
              <px:PXGridColumn DataField="SalesPersonID" ></px:PXGridColumn>
              <px:PXGridColumn DataField="SalesPersonID_SalesPerson_descr" ></px:PXGridColumn>
              <px:PXGridColumn DataField="LocationID" ></px:PXGridColumn>
              <px:PXGridColumn DataField="LocationID_description" ></px:PXGridColumn>
              <px:PXGridColumn DataField="CommisionPct" TextAlign="Right" ></px:PXGridColumn>
              <px:PXGridColumn DataField="IsDefault" Type="CheckBox" TextAlign="Center" ></px:PXGridColumn>
            </Columns>
            <RowTemplate>
              <px:PXLayoutRule runat="server" StartColumn="True" LabelsWidth="SM" ControlSize="M" ></px:PXLayoutRule>
              <px:PXSegmentMask ID="edSalesPersonID" runat="server" DataField="SalesPersonID" AutoRefresh="True" AllowEdit="True" ></px:PXSegmentMask>
              <px:PXSegmentMask ID="edLocationID" runat="server" DataField="LocationID" AutoRefresh="True" AllowEdit="True" ></px:PXSegmentMask>
              <px:PXTextEdit ID="edLocation_descr" runat="server" DataField="LocationID_description" Enabled="False" ></px:PXTextEdit>
              <px:PXNumberEdit ID="edCommisionPct" runat="server" DataField="CommisionPct" ></px:PXNumberEdit>
            </RowTemplate>
            <Mode InitNewRow="False" ></Mode>
            <Layout FormViewHeight="" ></Layout>
          </px:PXGridLevel>
        </Levels>
        <AutoSize Enabled="True" MinHeight="100" MinWidth="100" ></AutoSize>
        <ActionBar>
          <Actions>
            <Save Enabled="False" ></Save>
          </Actions>
        </ActionBar>
      </px:PXGrid>
    </Template>
  </px:PXTabItem>
```

It seems this gives the data fields their design template or something. After adding a similar section to my ASPX, the link appeared.