# How to place a 'Related Entity' lookup on a field

Tags: acumatica

In the Activity / Task screen (cr306020), there is a 'Related Entity' field with a PXSelector lookup as well as a pencil for opening the screen of the related entity:

[image]

I'd like to know if there is a way to do this for a custom field.  I've looked at the source code for the field (it's EPActivity.Source in the DAC), but I see nothing that puts these attributes on that field.  No PXSelector or anything similar.

Comment: Are you looking to simply add the pencil icon (form) / hyper link (grid column) to a field that when clicked takes you to another page? See if this post gives you what you need:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26387291/how-to-create-a-hyperlink-user-field/34190669#34190669

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example below shows how to add the Related Entity field on the **Opportunities** (CR304000) screen. Please be aware, PXRefNoteSelector control used in this sample is not currently supported by the Layout Editor in Acumatica Customization Manager. I used **Opportunities** to simplify and shorten the example. Unfortunately, for now you can only add the Related Entity field on a custom screen.

Now let's move forward to the sample:

1. Implement extension for the CROpportunity DAC to declare the database bound **UsrRefNoteID** and unbound **RelatedEntity** fields. Related Entity's NoteID will be stored in UsrRefNoteID, and RelatedEntity will be used to display Related Entity's user-friendly description:

   ```
   public class CROpportunityExt : PXCacheExtension<CROpportunity>
   {
       #region UsrRefNoteID
       public abstract class usrRefNoteID : IBqlField { }

       protected Guid? _UsrRefNoteID;

       [PXDBGuid]
       [PXParent(typeof(Select<CRActivityStatistics,
           Where<CRActivityStatistics.noteID, Equal<Current<CROpportunityExt.usrRefNoteID>>>>), LeaveChildren = true)]
       public Guid? UsrRefNoteID
       {
           get
           {
               return _UsrRefNoteID;
           }
           set
           {
               _UsrRefNoteID = value;
           }
       }
       #endregion

       #region Source
       public abstract class relatedEntity : IBqlField { }

       [PXString(IsUnicode = true)]
       [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Related Entity Description", Enabled = false)]
       [PXFormula(typeof(EntityDescription<CROpportunityExt.usrRefNoteID>))]
       public string RelatedEntity { get; set; }
       #endregion
   }
   ```
2. Create extension for the OpportunityMaint BLC to decorate its primary **Opportunity** data view with PXRefNoteSelectorAttribute. The PXRefNoteSelectorAttribute is required for the Edit (pencil) and Lookup buttons to work on your custom Related Entity field:

   ```
   public class OpportunityMaintExt : PXGraphExtension<OpportunityMaint>
   {
       [PXCopyPasteHiddenFields(typeof(CROpportunity.resolution))]
       [PXViewName(Messages.Opportunity)]
       [PXRefNoteSelector(typeof(CROpportunity), typeof(CROpportunityExt.usrRefNoteID))]
       public PXSelect<CROpportunity> Opportunity;
   }
   ```
3. On Aspx page, add PXRefNoteSelector control with the **DataField** property set to ***RelatedEntity*** and **NoteIDDataField** to ***UsrRefNoteID***. 
   For the **EditButton**, **LookupButton** and **LookupPanel** tags, use the primary data view name decorated with the PXRefNoteSelector attribute (*Opportunity* in the code snippet below)

   ```
   <pxa:PXRefNoteSelector ID="edRefEntity" runat="server" DataField="RelatedEntity" NoteIDDataField="UsrRefNoteID"
       MaxValue="0" MinValue="0" ValueType="Guid" CommitChanges="true">
       <EditButton CommandName="Opportunity$Navigate_ByRefNote" CommandSourceID="ds" />
       <LookupButton CommandName="Opportunity$Select_RefNote" CommandSourceID="ds" />
       <LookupPanel DataMember="Opportunity$RefNoteView" DataSourceID="ds" TypeDataField="Type" IDDataField="NoteID" />
   </pxa:PXRefNoteSelector>
   ```
4. Hide 3 actions generated by the PXRefNoteSelector attribute from the form toolbar. Use the same primary data view name decorated with the PXRefNoteSelector attribute (*Opportunity* in the code snippet below) as in the step above:

   ```
   <CallbackCommands>
       ...
       <px:PXDSCallbackCommand Name="Opportunity$Navigate_ByRefNote" Visible="False" />
       <px:PXDSCallbackCommand Name="Opportunity$Select_RefNote" Visible="False" />
       <px:PXDSCallbackCommand Name="Opportunity$Attach_RefNote" Visible="False" />
   </CallbackCommands>
   ```

You might also need to implement your own **EntityDescription** operator, since at the time this example was created, it had *internal* access modifier and was not available outside of the PX.Objects.dll:

```
public class EntityDescription<RefNoteID> : BqlFormulaEvaluator<RefNoteID>, IBqlOperand
    where RefNoteID : IBqlField
{
    public override object Evaluate(PXCache cache, object item, Dictionary<Type, object> pars)
    {
        Guid? refNoteID = (Guid?)pars[typeof(RefNoteID)];
        return new EntityHelper(cache.Graph).GetEntityDescription(refNoteID, item.GetType());
    }
}
```

And finally... screenshot of the customized **Opportunities** screen with a brand-new **Related Entity** field:

[image]

Comment: Thanks much, Ruslan - I'll give it a try soon.

Comment: Not sure  if you still  monitor this, Ruslan - but I'm confused about the CRActivityStatistics in your example.  What does this refer to, and how is it relevant to your example?  I guess I'm asking what the purpose is of the PXParent attribute in the declaration of UsrRefNoteID...