# I can't get the launch function to work on the Related Entity control

Tags: acumatica

This relates to and extends an existing StackOverflow case that has been answered - 
[How to place a 'Related Entity' lookup on a field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43237638/how-to-place-a-related-entity-lookup-on-a-field/43267135#43267135)  (many thanks to Acumatica support on this as well)

I have a custom screen that adds a 'Related Link' control, like this:

[image]

And this works as expected.   I've also included several custom screens as entities to link to by adding the NoteID, RefNoteID, RelatedEntity fields to their DACs and the PXRefNoteSelector attribute to their view declarations.  Everything works as expected, except that the pencil icon doesn't launch to the entity / screen that's been selected.

Is there something (an attribute, perhaps) that I'm missing in the DACs that needs to be added in order to launch to the selected entity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to decorate the custom entity DAC with `PXPrimaryGraph` attribute and pass the maintenance page graph type in parameter:

```
[PXPrimaryGraph(typeof(CustomEntityMaint))]
[Serializable]
public class CustomEntityDAC : PX.Data.IBqlTable
{

}
```