# How to add the OrderNbr hyperlink in SOLine

Tags: acumatica

I have a grid which displays only SOLine and SOOrder data.  In my case, SOLine is the main DAC, because the purpose of the grid is to perform mass updates of the transactions.  I wish to add the OrderNbr in the grid, so the user can select and open the sales order popup.  I notice the order number field does not appear as a hyperlink, if use SOOrder table in my grid.  Next I try SOLine.orderNbr.  However the field type is only TextEdit.  Here is a workaround

I created the SOLine cache extended and defined a non-bound field.  Something simple like ExtraSOOrder field.  Next I create a PXAction which creates the SOOrderEntry graph and performs the redirect, and achieves the goal.  I notice something odd in the grid.  OrderNbr is displayed twice.  Although the field is only added once in the grid, the webpage adds the field a second time.  In fact, the user is unable to remove the duplicate order number field, in the column selector.  The duplicate field has a yellow icon which I have not seen before.

What is the best way to add the redirect, to the sales order entry page?  The behavior works perfectly for the Inventory item field in this grid.  OrderNbr is more challenging.[image][image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a hyperlink user field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26387291/how-to-create-a-hyperlink-user-field)

Answer (score 1):

All that was required was to add the SOOrder.orderNbr to the grid columns collection.  Then assign the action to the Linkedcommand property, to that field.  No need to create a cache extension for all of this.

Comment: You only need the grid column as a PXSelector and the AllowEdit set to true. No need for a custom action/link command. Same idea if adding as a Generic Inquiry the GI knows the link via the selector of the sales order ordernbr field and the DAC primary graph. Just another alternative and less code to maintain. Use SOOrder.OrderNbr vs SOLine.OrderNbr