How to dynamically update NavigateURL property of a button with event handler that creates new URL
We have a button that has a default NavigateURL property that needs to be updated based on the value in a field of a record.  Has anyone ever been able to do this?  Can you provide sample code to accomplish this?

Where is the button? Is it belong to a grid or it is on a form?

Does this help answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26387291/how-to-create-a-hyperlink-user-field
You can via the action then adjust your code for the different URL
